# Is yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g good for production deployment over https

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I started getting the following error today for some reason. It was working fine until last week without complaining.  So I did the following after reasearching:

```
yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g
```

And yarn install worked. But it was slower than what it user to before. Since I a mtesting it locally, I am wondering if this setting is good for production environment where we are using https? I mean am I good to push the code with the above changes to gitlab and then use the same to deploy in production?

```
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.22.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel%2fplugin-proposal-throw-expressions: unable to get local issuer certificate".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\tan\\project\\testing related folders\\slowness_bug\\projectexplorer\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

More info if needed:

My node version is `v12.16.1` if needed. I am using Gitbash on Windows OS. My production environment is RHEL server.